# Xubuntu 15.04: Can no longer navigate with Ctrl + left/right on MySQL shell

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, mysql

In previous versions of Ubuntu (and other Linuxes), I was able to jump word-by-word in the MySQL shell with <kbd>Ctrl+←</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl+→</kbd>. This does not seem to work in 15.04. Instead I get `;5D` (<kbd>Ctrl+←</kbd>) and `;5C` (<kbd>Ctrl+→</kbd>) printed into the SQL query.

Using mysql-client-5.6.24-0ubuntu2 on Xubuntu 15.04 with all patches.

Is this a configuration problem or intentional behaviour?

Comment: It Works for bash?

Comment: Yes, in bash it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is apparently due to the fact that recent MySQL versions in Ubuntu [aren't compiled against `readline` anymore](https://bugs.launchpad.net/percona-server/+bug/1266386), but `editline` instead.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug reported for all Ubuntu like distributions (probably happens to other distros too). [Mysql is using editline lib instead of readline](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mysql-5.6/+bug/1443352) and that's breaking a lot of features we are used to, like <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> or  <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd>  to move between words, <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd> to reverse search, or even writing unicode characters is not possible.

Even when he bug is flagged as high, please support the request to change back to readline by adding yourself to the affected users.